# Getting error in Collection.create : Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a model

```
var TodoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title : '',
        completed: false
    }
});
```

When i tried to add this model to the collection using `Collection.create` method i am getting an error

> Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

I tried in the following way

```
var TodoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : TodoModel,
});

todoCollection.create({title:'Try out code examples', completed:true});
```

Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating a model/ collection -- by default you must specify a url for the resources. You could do this like the following:

```
var TodoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title : '',
        completed: false
    }
});

var TodoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/todos',
    model : TodoModel,
});
```

See http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url for more details.

I think the confusion here is coming from Backbone.js's Todo sample which uses local storage (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html). If you jump to the bottom of the localstorage code you can see **Backbone.sync** is set. By doing this we change the default behavior of creating models so that it no longer requires the Url. In most backbone applications this is not the case and a server side URL is required to make a model work.

Answer (score 1):

This is because destroy() function will call Backbone.sync to update the server too, not only your models in the frontend. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy

So, if you're using REST to sync your data, you'll need to set a url property in your model so Backbone know where to send request:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "http://myapi.com/"
})
```

To allow more flexibility, you can also set a urlRoot: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot

Or you can add

```
 Backbone.sync = function(method, model, success, error){
    success();
  }
```

To work your code.